# Will placing a strong magnet near my electric skateboard Li-Ion Battery pack damage or discharge it?

Tags: power, batteries, lithium-ion, magnet

The original clips securing my battery cover are broken and i thought of devising an alternate way to keep the cover shut involving a hard drive magnet and a hinge

the battery pack would sit in proximity (3-5 cm away) to the magnet while in use (1-2 hours/day), but I would remove it when the session ends.

Here's a rough plan. If  you can make any sense of my drawing skills, the battery pack sits right under the cover. The hard drive magnet would be inside the battery case (dashed trait)
[image: magnetic clasp for cover]

Before refining this idea I just wanna make sure this setup would not be harmful to my battery pack or other electronics (bluetooth remote receiver, ESC, ...).
What if I decide to switch to a LiPo battery pack later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know is there no direct harm to a lipo battery if you place a magnet next to it.

I have put magnets ofthen next to electronics to see what happens and never had some problems with that.

Also in the brushless motors you are going to use there are also fairly strong magnets inside of them, so don't worry.

I'm aware that this sin't a very scientific answer, but I'm not a lipo or ESC specialist. 
I'm just an experienced electronics guy. But I'm 99.99% sure nothing bad will hapen if you do this.

Comment: Thanks. I imagine if there was a strong counter indication  someone would have said so, answer accepted