# Any deleterious effect from very strong, close magnets on NiMH cells over time?

Tags: magnetics, nimh, battery-chemistry

This question probably isn't a perfect fit for this SE, but I did find this question: [Will placing a strong magnet near my electric skateboard Li-Ion Battery pack damage or discharge it?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312403/will-placing-a-strong-magnet-near-my-electric-skateboard-li-ion-battery-pack-dam)

This is a different situation, though: I would like to attach some small, powerful magnets to the outside of the thin aluminum casing of a single-AA-cell flashlight. These would only be at a distance of about 1-2mm from the side of the cell itself. Does anyone with strong physics/chemistry side-skills know if this would be likely to affect the battery over the course of sustained use (or sooner)? I'll probably victimize an old cell to test empircally, but it would be great if I could get some information in the short term.

Comment: are the batteries magnetic.  a strong magnet tends to accelerate rust in magetic steel ..e.g. inside car body will rust thru the paint within a few years from the inside

Comment: I found a report in which NMR imaging looked at the chemistry and dendrites, but there were no comments about strong magnets causing degradation

Comment: interesting point about the oxidation acceleration... the magnets do stick to the batteries, but my assumption is that this is purely due to the casing... I don't really know that for certain, though.

Comment: Charges moving in a magnetic field experience a force perpendicular to the magnetic field and direction of motion. But I don't think this will be a problem. The force is relatively small for slow particles. And the magnetic field lines from the magnet will curve around to get to the other pole on the magnet. It is not like you have a flux circuit forcing flux to travel through the body of the battery.